# AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Tags: apache, cron, cron-task, apscheduler, linode

I am running python's APScheduler in the background of my website's Django backend. However every 24 hours, at the same hour, I receive this SIGTERM caught error and the server is restarted which results in unacceptably wrong misfire times of around half on hour on my cron jobs. Can anybody help in solving this issue? Would be greatly appreciated!

[mpm_event:notice] [pid 31581:tid 140643445140416] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down